# Boot2docker with jenkins

Tags: docker

I want to install jenkins on Boot2docker but I could not solve it.My aim is to use continous integration with my spring boot project.On Centos,I can install jenkins but  with boot3docker how can I install jenkins.I made some researches, maybe I have to pull jenkins image after that I have to run the image on docker container.Is it a good idea to run jenkins from container?I saw a video,the instructor install jenkins on Centos without using container.

Comment: Yes, You can put jenkins on container as well as outside choice is yours. how you want to drive you CI/CD. here is the way how you can deploy jenkins on docker :https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/

Comment: I run the container with 'docker run -d -p 8080:8080 jenkins' command(I got a password) but I can not reach to localhost:8080.Maybe I have to change default port

Comment: can you share output of `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` ? It seems like ip forwarding is not enabled.

Comment: It gives sysctl command not found error.

Comment: mention OS and its version.

Comment: Thank you very much.It was opened.My vm's ip:8080 is running